# Is using parameters with GROQ injection safe?

Tags: security, code-injection, sanity, groq

After a bit of searching, I didn't find anything definitive. Does anyone know if the following example is safe from injection when using GROQ?

```
const query = '*[_type == 'car' && maker == $maker][0]';
const result = await sanityClient.fetch(query, { maker });
```

The `$maker` parameter would come from the URL, so I was wondering if someone could write a GROQ query that could be injected to hijack the intended query, causing harm.

This is just an example. I am hoping specifying `$maker` as a parameter makes it injection safe. I could also make the same query with string concatination, which *feels* less safe:

```
const query = `*[_type == 'car' && maker == '${maker}'][0]`;
```

The `sanityClient` comes from their `next-sanity` npm package.